# Deploying angular 8 application locally to IIS errors with 'The server responded with a non-Javascript MIME type of "text/html"?'

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, iis, single-page-application

I am trying to deploy angular 8 application that is hosted inside my ASP.NET Core application in wwwroot folder. Prior to upgrade to angular 8, I was able to accomplish this with the following configuration:

1. Configure the `web.config` file of the ASP.NET Core web api to use `ASPNETCORE_ENVIORNMENT=DEVELOPMENT`
2. Configure the angular `index.html` file `base href` to point to `/virtualApplicationName/`

When I view the network tab, all of the static files are downloading fine without issues:

[image]

But I keep seeing this:
[image]

Any ideas what else I can try?

Thanks

Comment: Have you  change the property "target" in the file "tsconfig.json" to "es5" ?

Comment: I just did that and I am not getting a different error I think I may be onto something. Thanks for commenting. The issue went away by changing it to ES5. post an answer and Ill accept it, because thats what the original issue was.

Comment: https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/2443/How-to-set-MIME-types-for-web-fonts-in-IIS.html try this

Comment: @O.MeeKoh just add my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the property "target" in the file "tsconfig.json" to "es5" and you should be good to go

```
"compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
}
```

Comment: that fixed my issue, but my IIS is now returning `index.html` file for all static file requests....

Comment: How do I accomplish the same thing targeting `ES2015`?